Does Background Fetch work in New Architecture?
When upgrading to expo 52 and enabling new architecture I noticed that background fetch isn't supported.
https://reactnative.directory/?search=background-fetch
Does that mean that if I need a set up a background task that does semi-random fetches I won't be able to in New Architecture?
